# Inbuilt directives do not work within custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

```js
var app = angular.module("myDiscuss", []);
app.controller("TabController", function() {
  this.tab = 0;
  this.subTab = 0;
  this.like = 0;

  this.selectLike = function(setTab) {
    this.like= setTab;
  };

  this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
    this.tab= setTab;
  };

  this.selectSubTab = function(setTab){
    this.subTab = setTab;
  };

  this.isSelected = (function(checkTab){
    return this.tab === checkTab;
  });

  this.isSelectedSub = (function(checkTab){
    return this.subTab === checkTab;
  });

  this.isSelectedLike = (function(checkTab) {
    return this.like === checkTab;
  });
  
});

app.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.person = {
    name: null
  };
  $scope.people = [];
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.person.name) {
      $scope.people.push({name: $scope.person.name});
      $scope.person.name = '';
    }
  };
});

app.directive('replyBox', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    templateUrl:'../templates/reply-box.html'
  };
});

app.directive ('commentSection', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    scope :{},
    templateUrl:'../templates/comment-section.html'
    
  };
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myDiscuss">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <div class="thumbnail" ng-controller="TabController as tabs">    
            <div ng-show="tabs.isSelectedLike(1)">
            </div>
            <section class="caption">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li ng-class="{ active:like === 1 }" >
                  <a href ng-click="tabs.selectLike(1)">Helpful</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-class= "{ active:tab === 2 }">
                  <a href ng-click="tabs.selectTab(2)">Comment</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div comment-section ng-show="tabs.isSelected(2)"></div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

<!--comment-section.html-->
<div class="panel" >
  <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="FormController">
    <blockquote ng-repeat="(index,object) in people" >
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{ active:subTab === 3 }" >
          <a href ng-click="tabs.selectSubTab(3)">Helpful</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class= "{ active:subTab === 4}">
          <a href ng-click="tabs.selectSubTab(4)">Reply</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div reply-box ng-show="tabs.isSelectedSub(4)"></div>
    </blockquote>
    <input type="text" ng-model="person.name" name="person.name" />
  </form>
</div>

<!-- reply-box.html -->
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

When I add the `reply-box` directive to the `comment-section` directive it does not perform the 'submit' action. When the "reply" link in the commentSection directive is clicked, the `ng-show` directive does not working for the `reply-box` directive.

Comment: Create a plunkr, also what is the error?

Comment: can you narrow down the code and give a smaller example?

Comment: remove the extra parentheses from your controller functions.

Comment: reply-box directive is not showing up on performing ng-click

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see any `input type='submit'` in your code, maybe thats why `ng-submit` is not working,

Moreover i think your `ng-show` directive isn't working because the `ng-controller="TabController as tabs"` ends here

```
     <div class="thumbnail" ng-controller="TabController as tabs">              
        <div ng-show="tabs.isSelectedLike(1)">
        </div>
        <section class="caption"  >
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{ active:like === 1 }" >
              <a href ng-click="tabs.selectLike(1)">Helpful</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class= "{ active:tab === 2 }">
              <a href ng-click="tabs.selectTab(2)">Comment</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div comment-section ng-show="tabs.isSelected(2)"></div>
        </section>
      </div>
```

Thus you are calling your `ng-show="tabs.isSelectedSub(4)"` wont return any thing because this method is not defined in your `FormController`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but when there were no custom directive it was working properly when whole code was in the same file
When the directive is removed from it the submit function works

Comment: so should I add the same function in the FormController also. or is there any method that the TabController's function could be used

Answer (score 0):

The errors occur because the scope for the comment section directive does not inherit from the parent scope.

### Define a scope that inherits from the parent scope

To inherit from the parent scope, you'll need to set the `scope` property of the `comment-section` directive to true.

From the [AngularJS documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> `scope: true` - the directive creates a new child scope that prototypically inherits from the parent scope. If more than one directive (on the same DOM element) requests a new scope, only one new child scope is created. Since we have "normal" prototypal inheritance, this is like ng-include and ng-switch, so be wary of 2-way data binding to parent scope primitives, and child scope hiding/shadowing of parent scope properties.

The `comment-section` directive can be rewritten thus:

```
app.directive ('commentSection', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    scope :true,
    templateUrl:'../templates/comment-section.html'

  };
});
```